# cambiar el grosor del editText

Tags: android-studio

Como puedo dejar la barra del edittext como la del primer campo que se ve mas gruesa, vi varias opciones pero ninguna funciono y no se si es del focus o que.
La diferencia es minima pero se nota porque el foco me agranda la linea

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/MyHintText">
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/amount"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textColor="@color/greenDark"
                android:maxLength="10"
                android:textSize="@dimen/simple_text_size_small"
                android:theme="@style/MyEditText" />
        </TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Añade el style que le aplicas, MyEditText

Comment: Puedes hacerlo creando un selector para configurar el background de tu EditText, aquí tienes un ejemplo [https://stackoverflow.com/a/25662035/5675636]

Comment: pero si da error el campo pierdo q se cambie de color?